# Morphisms from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field, and let $C$ be a projective curve over $K$. Consider a morphism $\varphi: \mathbb{P}^2 \to C$ over $Spec(K)$.

Is it true that $\varphi$ must be constant?

What I know so far: $\varphi$ is proper (since $\mathbb{P}^2$ is projective), hence closed, which means that the image is either a point of $C$ (in which case $\varphi$ is constant) or the whole of $C$. Now to see how things go in the latter case, I take an ample line bundle $L$ on $C$, which pulls back to the invertible sheaf $\varphi^*(L) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d)$ for some integer $d$.

1. If $d <0$, I don't understand why a morphism $\mathbb{P}^2 \to C$ cannot exist in this case.
2. If $d=0$, I don't understand why a morphism $\mathbb{P}^2 \to C$ must be constant in this case.
3. I'm not even sure what happens when $d>0$.

Comment: If onto, take two distinct points $p,q\in C$ and look at the inverse images. You can check that these are two  disjoint curves in the plane which is absurd.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for the hint. However I'm trying to use line bundles as the same technique seems to generalize to higher dimensions.

Comment: For a curve $L^2=0$ forcing $d=0$. Rest should be clear.

Comment: @Mohan would you care to elaborate on that? In particular, why would $d=0$ imply that $\varphi$ must be constant? I don't seem to understand the relationship between global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d)$ and morphisms $\mathbb{P}^2 \to C$.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: If $ C $ is the projective line, the assertion is clear because there are no non-constant morphisms from a projective space of higher dimension to one of lower dimension.

Case 2: If the genus of C is $ \ge 1 $, cover $ \mathbb{P}^2 $ by lines. A morphism $ f: \mathbb{P}^2 \to C $ is constant on every line because there are no non-constant morphisms from a curve of lower genus to one of higher genus. Hence $ f $ is constant.

Alternatively, there is a ramified cover $ C \to \mathbb{P}^1 $ and the composition of $ f $ with this leads to Case 1, a constant map. Hence, $ f $ is constant again.